# Matching the last group of something in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the problem to define the regexpression (for a Java program), that gives me the last matching group of something. The reason for that is the conversion of some text files (here: the export of some wiki) to the new format of the new wiki.

For example, when I have the following text:

```
Here another include: [[Include(a/a-1)]]
```

The hierarchy of the pages is:

```
/a
  /a-1
```

The old wiki referenced the hierarchy name, the new wiki will only have the title of the page. The new format should look like:

```
{include:a-1}
```

Currently I have the following regular expression:

```
/\[\[Include\(([^\)]+)\)\]\]/
```

which matches from the example above `a/a-1`, but I need a regular expression that matches only `a-1`.

Is it possible to construct a regular expression for java that matches the last group only?

So for the following original lines:

```
[[Include(a)]]
[[Include(a/b)]]
[[Include(a/a-1)]]
[[Include(a/a-1/a-2)]]
```

I would like to match only

```
a
b
a-1
a-2
```

Comment: FYI, tweaked he answer so it does not just capture the groups, but also show the search and replace regex (ps see demo). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you're looking for. Group 1 has the text you want, see the captures pane at the bottom right of the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vW0oS8), as well as the Substitutions pane at the bottom.

EDIT: per your request, replaced the `[a-z0-9-]` with `[^/]` (Did not update the regex101 demo as this regex, which I confirmed to work, breaks in regex101, which uses `/` as a delimiter, even when escaping the `/`. However here is another [demo](http://fiddle.re/j1erx) on regexplanet)

Search:

```
\[\[Include\((?:[^/]+\/)*([^/]+)\)\]\]
```

Replace:

```
{include:$1}
```

**How does it work?**

After the opening bracket of the Include, we match a combination of characters such as a-1 (made of letters, dash and digits) followed by a forward slash, zero or more times, then we capture the last such combination of characters.

In the few languages that support infinite-width lookbehinds, we could match what you want without relying on Group 1 captures.

Comment: This answer is nearly perfect, thank you a lot! Could you adapt it by changing `...(?:[-a-z0-9]+/)` (which matched my examples) to something like `...(?:[^/]+/)` which matches everything that could be in a title of a page (but no forward slash)?

Comment: And one extrapoint (who could give zx82 that) for providing a demo, that is a handy tool!!

Comment: @mliebelt Thanks for your feedback. :) Changed the regex per your request. It works but breaks the regex101 demo which has a bug related to their `/` delimiter.

Comment: @zx81 You could easily use `\[\[Include\(.*?([a-z0-9-]+)\)\]\]`

Comment: @hwnd Yes, that's true. But both my earlier solution `(?:[-a-z0-9]+/)` and the one @mliebelt requested `[^/]+` are faster, because as you know the `.*?` causes backtracking at every step.

Comment: I'm importing currently the wiki pages, and the regular expression works like a charm :-)

Comment: @mliebelt Terrific, glad to hear you're getting some good work done. :)